# HttpWebRequest and Response Issues

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

So i have this class that I use for HTTPwebrequests. In this instance of my program I'm posting some data as well as a cookie. Now heres the really wierd part. I use fiddler to sniff headers and monitor the traffic of my program in testing. If fiddler is open this function works just fine. If fidler is closed whenever I go to post anydata the operation times out. It always does this. No matter what I do. Can any one shed some light on this as I'm pulling my hair out in frustration.

```
    Public Function Send(ByVal URL As String, _
    Optional ByVal PostData As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal Method As HTTPMethod = HTTPMethod.HTTP_GET, _
    Optional ByVal ContentType As String = "", Optional ByVal Refer As String = "")

    Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
    Dim Response As HttpWebResponse
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
    Dim SW As StreamWriter
    Dim SR As StreamReader
    Dim ResponseData As String
    Dim a As New CookieContainer()
    ' Request.Proxy = New WebProxy("173.234.250.164", 3128)
    ' Prepare Request Object
    Request.Method = Method.ToString().Substring(5)
    Request.CookieContainer = a
    ' Set form/post content-type if necessary
    If (Method = HTTPMethod.HTTP_POST AndAlso PostData <> "" AndAlso ContentType = "") Then
        ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    End If


    'Set User Agent
    Request.UserAgent = ("Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; GTB6.6)")

    'Set Refer
    If (Refer <> "") Then
        Request.Referer = Refer
    End If


    ' Set Content-Type
    If (ContentType <> "") Then
        Request.ContentType = ContentType
        Request.ContentLength = PostData.Length
    End If

    'Set Cookie If Given
    If (Cookie <> "") Then
        Request.Headers.Add("cookie", Cookie)
    End If


    ' Send Request, If Request
    If (Method = HTTPMethod.HTTP_POST) Then
        Try
            Debug.Print("Inside Post")
            SW = New StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream())
            SW.Write(PostData)
            Debug.Print("Wrote Post Data")
        Catch Ex As Exception
            Throw Ex
        Finally
            SW.Close()
        End Try
    End If

    ' Receive Response
    Try
        Response = Request.GetResponse()
        For Each cook As Cookie In Response.Cookies
            Cookie = Cookie & cook.ToString() & ";"
        Next
        Debug.Print(Cookie)

        SR = New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
        ResponseData = SR.ReadToEnd()
    Catch Wex As System.Net.WebException
        SR = New StreamReader(Wex.Response.GetResponseStream())
        ResponseData = SR.ReadToEnd()
        Throw New Exception(ResponseData)
    Finally
        SR.Close()
    End Try

    Return ResponseData


End Function
```

Comment: I had a similar issue with WCF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646985/wcf-client-hang-on-service-interruption/1659667#1659667 . Though it looks like you are applying the same setting programmatically, so it doesn't look like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're never disposing the `HttpWebResponse` - which means the connection is going to be held open. You should use a `Using` statement for `Response`. (I'd also suggest that you declare variables as late as possible, rather than declaring everything at the top of the method... and that you use `Using` statements everywhere instead of closing things in `Finally` blocks.

Note that you're also closing `SR` in a finally block when it may not be set - if some exception you weren't expecting is thrown, your attempt to close `SR` may throw a `NullReferenceException`. Personally I'd treat the two StreamReaders (one in the success case and one in the failure case) separately.